# Sum related to Goodman's Formula

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring, extremal-combinatorics, extremal-graph-theory

Suppose I have a (improper) 2-coloring of $E(K_n)$. Define the graph of all red edges to be $G$ and the graph of all blue edges to be $G'$. Then Goodman's formula says that the total number of triangles in $K_n$ is
$$ \Delta = \frac{1}{2} \left(\sum_{v \in V(G)} \binom{d_G(v)}{2} + \sum_{v \in V(G')}\binom{d_{G'}(v)}{2} - \binom{n}{3}\right)$$
Given this, what would the sum
$$ S = \sum_{v \in V(G)} \binom{d_G(v)}{2} + \sum_{v \in V(G')}\binom{d_{G'}(v)}{2}$$
represent?

Comment: How do you get a $2$ coloring for the complete graph? That does not imply $n<3$?

Comment: @Phicar, I think the OP means a not necessarily proper edge 2-coloring.

Comment: Isn't $V(G)=V(G')$?

Comment: @RobPratt ok, i see. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about that, I have updated the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are essentially taking $2$ different kinds of triangles: The ones that have $2$ edges of one color and $1$ edge of a different color and the ones that have $3$ edges of the same color. Notice that the former are counted once because you have to be in the vertex(index of the sums) in which the $2$ colors collide. Notice that the later is counted $3$ times because each of the vertex is giving once the triangle. So, $$S=\text{# of triangles with at least two colors}+3\times \text{# of triangles with same color}.$$
The formula above works because you eliminate the first possibility and then divide by $2$ so you were counting the number of triangles where all edges had the same color.